# Recover kops Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kops

There's a kubernetes cluster that was created by kops 
and when running `kops validate` this is the output:

```
    INSTANCE GROUPS
NAME            ROLE    MACHINETYPE MIN MAX SUBNETS
master-us-east-1a   Master  m4.xlarge   1   1   us-east-1a
nodes           Node    c4.2xlarge  1   75  us-east-1a

NODE STATUS
NAME                ROLE    READY
ip-172-20-59-93.ec2.internal    master  False

VALIDATION ERRORS
KIND    NAME                MESSAGE
Machine i-0a44bbdd18c86e846     machine "i-0a44bbdd18c86e846" has not yet joined cluster
Machine i-0d3302056f3dfeef0     machine "i-0d3302056f3dfeef0" has not yet joined cluster
Machine i-0d6199876b91962f4     machine "i-0d6199876b91962f4" has not yet joined cluster
Node    ip-172-20-59-93.ec2.internal    master "ip-172-20-59-93.ec2.internal" is not ready

Validation Failed
```

How I can recover this cluster? The s3 files for this cluster are available.

The etcd volumes show status as "in-use"

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kops stores the state of your cluster in S3.

1. Find the bucket where the state is stored
2. Set `export KOPS_STATE_STORE=s3://your-k8s-state-store`
3. Run `kops update cluster`
4. If that fails.
5. Terminate all your instances related to the cluster
6. Run `kops create cluster`

Note that the internal state of your cluster is not in S3 but in etcd. The answer here has more details about this topic and also how to backup/restore etcd: [How to restore kubernetes cluster using kops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51408546/how-to-restore-kubernetes-cluster-using-kops)

Comment: one additional step I had to do is make the maxSize and minSize of the master node to 0 , run update cluster. Make it back to 1 and run update cluster.